# json_decode array returns Illegal string offset error

Tags: php, json

The return of a webservice call looks like this:

```
"{\"result\": [\"893493\"]}"
```

Now if use `$result = json_decode($result , true)` I get the following string:

```
{"result": ["893493"]}
```

However, trying to access the array using `$result["result"]` I get the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'result' in /home/site/wwwroot/json_test.php on line 81
```

What is missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the exact code. I tried  `$result = json_decode("{\"result\": [\"893493\"]}" , true);
echo $result["result"][0];` it worked fine.

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/QIDhn

Comment: It sounds like the webservice is returning the actual quoted string, in which case you'll need to run `json_decode` twice - once to get the JSON itself, and again to decode it into a PHP array. Like the error message says, you've still got a string after you decode it.

Comment: Yes, that't it! I had to decode it twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the webservice returned a quoted string, result had to be decoded twice:

```
$result = json_decode(json_decode($result , true), true);
```